# Referencing a control programatically with external source

Tags: database, vb.net, textbox, reference

Forgive me about the title, I have no idea what this is called.

I have a MS Access database set up, with a `Period` field that has either values 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5. I retrieve these values using a database connection and I would like to reference a particular control based on what period was grabbed from the database.

Here's example code, pseudo of course.

```
TextBox(dr(3)).Text = dr(0)
```

`dr(3)` contains the period, and dr(0) contains the content I would like to put into the text box. I have these text boxes on my form: `TextBox1`, `TextBox2`, `TextBox3`, `TextBox4` and `TextBox5`.

So if `dr(3)` contained `2` then I would want to reference `TextBox2`.

I hope I've made myself clear, any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this:

```
CType(Me.Controls("Textbox" & dr(3)), TextBox).text = dr(0)
```

The key point is that you can use the Controls collection of the container of the textboxes to reference the textbox you want